# Is there a way to run LibreSSL on Windows?

Tags: windows, libressl

I would like to use LibreSSL instead of OpenSSL on Windows, but I found no distribution yet. Did I miss it? Or is there a not too complicated way to compile it myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

libressl has supported Windows 7, Windows 8, and Windows Vista since Dec 2, 2014

http://undeadly.org/cgi?action=article&sid=20141201141720

As of yesterday, release version 2.2.1 of libressl now supports in addition:

- Windows XP
- Windows 2009 (aka Windows POS, embedded)
- Windows NT 2003-2012

To use libressl on Windows, just download it and follow the instructions included in the README.  DLLs are included.

Answer (score 1):

Update:

As stated in the ChangeLog of version 2.1.2 released on 2014-12-04, LibreSSL now at least  support mingw-w64.

> - Added initial Windows mingw-w64 support

We would be expecting LibreSSL to support more compilers in the future, and even CMake.

---

Old post:

As the [README](https://github.com/libressl-portable/portable/blob/master/README) suggests:

> LibreSSL portable will build on any reasonably modern version of Linux,
>   Solaris, or OSX with a standards-compliant compiler and C library.

There is currently no direct way to build it on Windows.

However, [BoringSSL](https://boringssl.googlesource.com/boringssl), another fork of OpenSSL which has CMake build scripts would build on Windows. I would think there is a chance to adapt the CMake scripts from BoringSSL to LibreSSL so that LibreSSL can be built on Windows. There might need some code changes too.

You can also give [openssl-cmake](http://www.valvers.com/open-software/projects/openssl-cmake/) a try.

Answer (score 1):

The LibreSSL team stopped compiling binaries for Windows since version 2.5.5. So I compiled it. LibreSSL 3.2.0 for Windows is available at this link (https://sourceforge.net/projects/libressl-3-2-0-for-windows/files/). I needed it about a year ago, so I made some builds available.

Comment: Try to add a little context around the link.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, LibreSSL 2.1.2 builds on Windows..

Comment: A little bit more Information for OP would be nice i think.